# White space to the right of an image html

Tags: html, css, image

Why is there white space to the right of my image?

HTML file:

```
...
<body>
    <div class="image">
        <img src="image.jpg" alt="Picture here" id="image" align="middle"></img>
    </div>
</body>
```

Here's what it looks like:

[image]

The image should just be the giraffe. Where is this white space coming from?

Comment: what is the size of your image? does it fit  to the space?

Comment: set `.image` to `display:inline-block` by default `div` is a `block` element

Comment: Why is everyone downvoting...?? Clearly someone who isn't that familiar yet with HTML behaviour and is asking for help.

Comment: @Christophe there are a lot of trolls in stackoverflow. If he doesn't stay according with a question or an answer he downvote without explanation. That's prohibited in stackoverflow, but they make it.

Comment: @MarcosPérezGude yes but people should be forced to add a comment to downvote. so you can at least see who and why.

Comment: Yes it's because I said that's prohibited in S.O. In the rules it says that if you downvote, leave a comment why.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, everyone. Where beginners are discouraged to ever post in this community.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure if you want the image full width or if the white bg color bothers you...

Make sure your image div has a blue background

```
.image {
    background-color: #4099FF;
}
```

or the parent that wraps your content and image. in this case your body

```
body {
    background-color: #4099FF;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the response.

Answer (score 1):

Its because your not filling the whole page your image is to small and you div is not full width

```
div{
    width: 100%; // full width
}
img{
    height: auto;
    width: 100%
}
```

this will stretch to fill the whitespace

Answer (score 1):

Depends on what you are trying to do, if you want the image to stretch the full width, you could set width:100%, but this would likely result in a very badely pixelated image and I dont recommend this

You may be better placing the image in a full width div, setting that div,s background color to blue and centering the image, or positioning it where you want it to be